# Process finished with exit code 1 while getting Font

Tags: python, pyside2

I have some simple code that grabs the font from my resources directory and assigns it to a `QFont`

I can't get anything to print, none of the variables. It just keeps returning exit code 1.

Sorry I don't really know what exactly to try here. So I have nothing show of what I tried. I did make sure to test that the `FONT_PATH` is going to a correct file. Also this function seems to work fine when called from a `QApplication`

```py
from PySide2 import QtGui, QtCore
import os

def get_font():

    FONT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__, os.pardir, os.pardir, 'resources', 'ProximaNova-Regular.ttf'))
    FONT_DB = QtGui.QFontDatabase()
    FONT_ID = FONT_DB.addApplicationFont(FONT_PATH)
    FAMILIES = FONT_DB.applicationFontFamilies(FONT_ID)
    BOLD_FONT = QtGui.QFont('Proxima Nova')

    return BOLD_FONT

print get_font()
```

What I'm expecting:

`<PySide2.QtGui.QFont( "Proxima Nova....") at 0x000....>`

What I'm getting:

`Process finished with exit code 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your script in the CMD/terminal you will get the following error message:

```
QFontDatabase: Must construct a QGuiApplication before accessing QFontDatabase
```

And that message indicates that you must have a QGuiApplication (or QApplication) before using QFontDatabase, so in your case you must create it if it does not exist:

```py
import os

from PySide2 import QtGui, QtCore


def get_font():
    app = QtGui.QGuiApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QtGui.QGuiApplication([])
    FONT_PATH = os.path.abspath(
        os.path.join(
            __file__, os.pardir, os.pardir, "resources", "ProximaNova-Regular.ttf"
        )
    )
    FONT_DB = QtGui.QFontDatabase()
    FONT_ID = FONT_DB.addApplicationFont(FONT_PATH)
    FAMILIES = FONT_DB.applicationFontFamilies(FONT_ID)
    BOLD_FONT = QtGui.QFont("Proxima Nova")
    return BOLD_FONT


print(get_font())
```